# Where is the best location for an app made ​​in NodeJS on a server?

Tags: linux, web-applications, node.js

For some time I am developing an application in `Nodejs`. And I asked where in the Linux file system on a server was the best place to leave it running. Since `PHP5` and `Apache2` is in `/var/www` , and tomcat has its own system.

I wonder where is the best place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't really matter where you put your Node.js but more how you set up this place. The right permissions are most important.

Possible locations (from a logical point of view) are:

```
/opt/<appname>
/usr/local/share/<appname>
/var/nodejs/<appname>
```

Comment: I guess it must be permissions only for root and run?

Comment: It is more secure to run node.js not as root (if possibe) and let the directories have the owner of the server user